# How do I delete messages specified by a number range?

Tags: mutt

The delete-by-pattern is the `D` command. But how can I specify a range, say from message number 1234 through 2345? Using `D` with something like `1234-2345` obviously fails because it treats it as a pattern, not a range of message numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `~m` [pattern](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns).

```
~m 1234-2345
```

You would need to use `~m` even to delete a single message by its number (or, of course, you could move to it and use `d`).

Answer (score 15):

This was very helpful, but still wasn't quite obvious to a complete newbie like me.  In gory detail...

- Type `D`
- `mutt` responds with

  > Delete messages matching:
- Type a response following the pattern:

  ```
  ~m 1234-2345
  ```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the accepted answer...

Comment: I will grant that it's merely a combination of the question and the accepted answer; however, it connects the dots, so you don't have to, and that's apparently valuable to several voters.  It's exactly the correct procedure in 3 bullet points.